# WSO2 Data Services - Is possible receive the full exception in the "Reponse" block when I use the try tool?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

When I use the try tool of WSO2 Data Services in link:

> .../services/User_DataService?tryit

The exceptions generated for the data service are accessible just in the log file, within the sever (.../repository/log/wso2carbon.log).

Is possible receive the full exception in the "Reponse" block when I use the try tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you are getting a SOAP fault message with proper reasoning in Data Services when an exception occurs. You will not be getting the complete error log as it is but a meaningful to understand it.

Comment: Hi Shelan, thanks! 

It was an idea for be faster the development.

I will use in this way!